# GCP Pubsub Nodejs client promises hang, client freezes, no errors

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

Promises hang with no errors, with a Google's Pub/Sub Node client library against your project.

Example:

```js
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

async function start() {
  const pubsubClient = new PubSub({ projectId: "my-project-id" });

  try {
    const [topics] = await pubsubClient.getTopics();
    console.log(topics);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
start().catch(console.error);
```

would return no error and no progress would be shown. Eventually the client times out after 10 minutes. No topics would get returned. The same goes for publishing to a topic, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used emulator pubsub for local development you have set `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` variable. For some reason it leads to the issue. Remove it from your environment with `unset PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` or remove it from your `.env` file and restart the server.

You can check if it is set with `printenv` in your shell (or [run `exec` from the node app](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js) to check)

There is a known issue and there are associated Github Issues, so if you came across this answer and it helped, feel free to let the maintainers know here:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/339
or here:
https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/issues/208
as it's a won't fix as seems to not affect many people.